# Delete code pattern using sed?

Tags: sed

I want to use sed to delete part of code (paragraph) beginning with a pattern and ending with a semicolon (`;`).

Now I came across an example to delete a paragraph separated by new lines

```
sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/Pattern/!d'
```

I'm confused how to use semicolon not as a delimiter but as a pattern instead.
Thanks.

Comment: Please show example data and expected results.

Comment: Yes sure input, http://pastebin.com/hHXJjtiS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Other option is to use the GNU extension of address range.</strike>

Next example means: delete everything from a line which begins with *pattern* until a line ending with semicolon.

```
sed '/pattern/,/;$/ d' infile
```

---

**EDIT to comment of Harsh**:

Try next `sed` command:

```
sed '/^\s*LOG\s*(.*;\s*$/ d ; /^\s*LOG/,/;\s*$/ d' infile
```

Explanation:

```
/^\s*LOG\s*(.*;\s*$/ d            # Delete line if begins with 'LOG' and ends with semicolon.
/^\s*LOG/,/;\s*$/ d               # Delete range of lines between one that begins with LOG and 
                                  # other that ends with semicolon.
```

Comment: the code you show does not rely on any GNU extensions to address range processing. This would work with the original sed 20+ years ago ;-) Good luck to all!

Comment: Would work only if input is in single line. correct me if i'm wrong. So shouldn't hold buffer be required. Sample http://pastebin.com/hHXJjtiS

Comment: @Harsh: I added the `sed` scripts that gives the output you expect.

Comment: thank you all. I learned few new things related to sed. (i'm new to post to stackoverflow, so pardon my formatting, couldn't even enter new line, so used pastebin). Thanks

Comment: One more question: My aim was to remove LOG from a file. Now for long arguments it can span over multiple lines (1,2,3 or so many lines). Delete a paragraph(or line) beginning with LOG and ending with (first) semicolon. I would try to modify it but i fail when it isn't a paragraph and is in single line.  (Between why return statement is handled specially ! )

Comment: I might be wrong but I think @Harsh wants to remove any `LOG(...);` statements.

Comment: @potong Yes, I aim to do that. it can be in 1 line or in a paragraph (block) spanning few lines.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
cat <<! >file
> a
> b
> ;
> x
> y
> ;
> !
sed '/^[^;]*$/{H;$!d};x;s/;//;/x/!d' file  

x
y
```

Explanation:

- For any line the does not have a single `;` in it `/^[^;]*$/`
- Append the above line to the hold space (HS) and delete the pattern space (PS) and begin the next iteration unless it is the last line in the file. `{H;$!d}`
- If a line is empty `/^$/` or the last line of the file:

  - Swap to the HS `x`
  - Delete the first `;` `s/;//`
  - Search for pattern (`x`) and if not found delete the PS `/x/!d`

N.B. This finds any pattern `/x/` to find the *beginning* pattern use `/^x/`.

EDIT:

After having seen your data and expected result, this may work for you:

```
sed '/^\s*LOG(.*);/d;/^\s*LOG(/,/);/d' file
```